# Is it possible to change the Facebook Comments assotiation URL somehow?

Tags: facebook, migration, comments, url-scheme

We have recently changed our URL scheme of some pages on our site to gain a little SEO boost. For example, `domain.tld/$id/slug/` -> `domain.tld/$category/slug-$id/`.

However the comments associated to the old URLs are now obviously not shown on the new URLs as the links are generated automatically using the new scheme.

As our site is very new, we don't have many comments yet.  Obviously we would hate to lose those few comments we already have and would rather migrate their association to the new URL scheme. I haven't found such option on the Comment Moderation Tool and the comments documentation doesn't elaborate on this either. Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I never tried this, but I imagine that having the old pages return a 301/302 redirect to the new ones would do the trick.

This way, you would keep pointing your comments to the OLD pages' URLs, not the new ones.

Comment: the old pages return 301 redirect to the new ones, but it doesn't make any effect to the facebook comments

Comment: Okay I can imagine this would work. However I don't like keeping the handler for old URLs around in my code for longer time than it's necessary to allow search engines to update their indices. So this would work only for a limited time and once I would remove that handler I might lose much more comments...so I'm not marking this as accepted. Thanks though.

Comment: I don't believe you have a choice. In the interest of protecting their users, I imagine there's no way Facebook will allow anyone to migrate comments from one URL to another.

Comment: I don't really see how would they protect their users by not allowing a site owner to migrate comments from one URL to another. Given that there probably is no solution for my problem, I guess I will be generating a more-generic data-urls for comments, something like domain.tld/comments/type/$id/ to prevent myself from losing comments again should we change the page URL scheme again.

Comment: Oh, Daniel :) Imagine what would happen if people just migrated your comments on, say, horses, to a child modeling site. That would be interesting :) «I'd really love to ride this one!» wouldn't sound as appropriate then!

Comment: I don't see that being any relevant given that I can go and create a page displaying whatever content I want, and display facebook comments from any other page in the world, just using the relevant href :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6486/discussion-between-daniel-grezo-and-julio-santos)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<fb:comments href="http://www.domain.com/oldurl"></fb:comments>
```